# I pickled my tuple

Tags: python, tuples, pickle

I'm still new to python. I'm working the framework for a larger project. This program makes you think of either a circle or square, then it ask four questions, then decides on an answer.

I'm on the last step of the framework, but ran into a problem. I get "global name 'qas1' is not defined"

> Line 50 in getQuestion   question = 'qas'    Global name 'qas' is not defined

This happend when I tried to pickle my tuples.

Here is my loading program to create the pickle file that contains my tuples:

```
import cPickle
import os

qas1 = [
('Are you more like Waffle or a Pancake'), 
('1. Waffle', 1, 0),
('2. Pancake', 0, 1)
]

qas2 = [
('Do you have a straight edge?'),
('1. Yes', 1, 0),
('2. No', 0, 1)
]

qas3 = [
('Are you simliar in shape to a lolipop?'),
('1. Yes', 0, 1),
('2. No', 1, 0)
]
qas4 = [
('Is the world rounded like a planet, or flat like a map?'),
('1. Rounded', 0, 1),
("2. Flat", 1, 0)
]

def hasFile():
    print 'I see the file'
    qas_file = open('qas.dat', 'r')
    qas1 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas2 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas3 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas4 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas_file.close
    confirmer()

def noFile():
    print 'I dont see a file...'
    saver()

def confirmer():
    print qas1
    print qas2
    print qas3
    print qas4

def saver():
    qas_file = open('qas.dat', 'w')
    print 'No worries, creating one now'
    cPickle.dump(qas1, qas_file)
    cPickle.dump(qas2, qas_file)
    cPickle.dump(qas3, qas_file)
    cPickle.dump(qas4, qas_file)
    qas_file.close
    print 'all done'

fname = "qas.dat"
if os.path.isfile(fname):
    hasFile()
else:
    noFile()
```

The code worked okay, but when I tried to use the file that it created I ran into problems.

```
import cPickle

#Counters
counterCircle = 0
counterSquare = 0

# tuples
def hasFile():
    print 'I see the file'
    qas_file = open('qas.dat', 'r')
    qas1 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas2 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas3 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas4 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas_file.close



#varibles Im made to assign
messageDisplayed = 0
question = 'beer'

#prints to screen   
def showQaA():
    print question[0]
    print question[1][0]
    print question[2][0]

#recieves and implements responses
def getResponce():
    global counterCircle
    global counterSquare
    global qas1, qas2, qas3, qas4
    ansew = raw_input('>> ')
    if ansew == "1":
        counterSquare = counterSquare + question[1][1]#(+1)
        counterCircle = counterCircle + question[1][2]#(+0)
    elif ansew == "2":
        counterSquare = counterSquare + question[2][1]#(+0)
        counterCircle = counterCircle + question[2][2]#(+1)
    print counterCircle
    print counterSquare


#Gets the current tuple infomation to display (Will be more advanced)
def getQuestion():
    global question
    if messageDisplayed == 0:
        question = qas1
    elif messageDisplayed == 1:
        question = qas2
    elif messageDisplayed == 2:
        question = qas3
    elif messageDisplayed == 3:
        question = qas4
    else:
        print 'youre screwd'

#figures out and prints results
def results():
    print "This is the circle results", counterCircle
    print "This is the square results", counterSquare
    if counterSquare < counterCircle:
        print "You are a circle!"
    elif counterSquare > counterCircle:
        print "You are a square!"
    else:
        print "You are the elusive squircle!"

#mainLoop currently set to 4 questions
hasFile()
while messageDisplayed <=3:
    getQuestion()
    showQaA()
    getResponce()
    messageDisplayed +=1
results()
```

It is **a lot** of code to look at, I know. When the program first loads the name `qas1` it reconizes that it is a tuple, but when I try to pass the properties to 'question' in `getQuestion()`: it forgets what they were. Any ideals what the problem is?

Comment: classic question title :)

Comment: Side note: In `hasFile` you've written `qas_file.close`. This results in a reference to the `close` method of `qas_file`, but does not *call* it. You need the parens (`qas_file.close()`) or your file handle with dangle until python shuts down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second file, qas[1-4] are all local to the `hasFile` function. Make them global, and your code will work:

```
def hasFile():
   global qas1, qas2, qas3, qas4
   # etc
```

The same bug occurs in the first code, but it is harder to notice - the four variables are still assigned only in the function - this *shadows* the identically-named global variables, leaving them unchanged. However, since loading them isn't expected to change their content, it appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

In hasFile(), you are setting the values of qas1, qas2, qas3, and qas4, but you aren't declaring them as global first, which means they aren't set in the global scope.

```
# tuples
def hasFile():
    global qas1, qas2, qas3, qas4 # <-- global declaration
    print 'I see the file'
    qas_file = open('qas.dat', 'r')
    qas1 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas2 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas3 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas4 = cPickle.load(qas_file)
    qas_file.close
```

In every function you set global variables, you need to explicitly declare them as global. See [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them).

Also, in the future, consider passing values to functions instead of using global variables, which can be error-prone, especially for beginners.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still not sure how to pass varibles within functions, Ima noob.

Comment: Now I am trying to get rid of my globals. All forums seem to suggest to avoid them like the plauge. I was able to turn "question" to local, but I'm having trouble with my counters. The only ideal I have is to try to save them to a txt file or pickle them, and then reload when the loop restarts. Would this be a bad practice?

Comment: @user3479560 You could store variables outside of your program, pickled or in text files, but this is not very useful unless you want something saved for future program executions. I think managing them in your main loop would work the best. You could have getResponce() return different values for square or circle. I would recommend becoming familiar with functions, arguments, returning things, etc., so you can see how many programs are structured and get functions working together with no globals. There's a lot to learn, but your code will be more organized and reusable. Good luck!

Comment: @user3479560 I'm partial to the [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) book if you're looking for any tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

When you just assign a variable like qas with a new value, as you do in `hasFile()`, you're creating a local var... not a global. Make sure to specify `global qas` before you simply assign to it.